# Android Design Tools freezing a lot in Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Can anyone help me figure out why the Android Design Tools plugin in Intellij IDEA crashes a lot when I use the design tab of the xml activities? I looked all over the internet and didn't find anything related.

I can't use Android Studio, for some reason it doesn't open on my PC.

In some olders versions of Intellij IDEA, that's works fine.

Comment: Post the [thread dumps](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899) for the freezes.